# Disabling all hammer.js (angular-hammer) events except single tap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, touch, hammer.js

My app uses [angular-hammer](https://ryanmullins.github.io/angular-hammer/), and I want to optimize it for only the **tap** event, to get the best performance because I don't need any other gestures. I understand hammer only adds listeners for the nominated `hm-*` options, but I want to explicitly prevent it from listening for other events (specifically double tap). I don't know whether this is necessary or not. (The app is quite intensive on button presses, and I have learned that this is a weakness of hybrid development across iOS and Android; I want to get it right.)

The arguments I am using are below, with my explanations in the annotations. Is this good practice, and the best I can do?

```js
// do not propagate further events (like pan or swipe) from clicking this element
hm-manager-options="{'touchAction':'none'}"   

// disable double tap so it knows any tap is a single tap 
hm-recognizer-options="[
    {'type':'tap','event':'tap'}, 
    {'type':'dbltap','enabled':'false'}
]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is a very old question, but if you are only interested in the Tap event, then why not just use ng-click?  That is a single-tap (or mouse click).

It sounds like you really might not need Hammer at all.  If you just need a simple tap event handler, perhaps [Bob Nisco's onLongPress directive](http://bobnisco.com/blog/view/onlongpress-angularjs-directive) could be used.  You would just need to strip out a few bits to get only the touch-sensitive event that you might be looking for.

[Here's a Plunk that has an onTap directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/1EBxlj?p=preview) based on Bob Nisco's work. It fires the assigned handler only if there is a touch event - **not a mouse click**.  Here's the app, controller, and directive:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = ['Item 1', 'Thing 2', 'Stuff part 3'];
  $scope.messages = ['No events yet'];
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.myTapHandler = function(item) {
    $scope.messages.unshift('Tap: ' + item);
  }

});

app.directive('onTap', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $elm, $attrs) {
      $elm.bind('touchend', function(evt) {
        // Prevent the onLongPress event from firing
        $scope.longPress = false;
        // If there is an on-touch-end function attached to this element, apply it
        if ($attrs.onTap) {
          $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.$eval($attrs.onTap)
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Here's the important HTML bits:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h3>Things to long-press</h3>
  <p ng-repeat="item in list" on-tap="myTapHandler(item)">
    [{{ item }}]
  </p>

  <h3>Messages (instead of console)</h3>
  <p ng-repeat="msg in messages">{{msg}}</p>
</body>
```